# Problem with looped class that is suposed call an action when intersecting with another object

Tags: javascript, loops, class, intersection

Sorry for the bad title.

I have some circles that when intersecting with an object that is dragged by the mouse should trigger a function to change the background color.
I want to have the circles (called balls) looped because I want there to be many of the same circle. So I have created a  class that I have later looped. The object (called player) is also from the same class that I have set the x and y position to follow the mouse.

My problem is that I can't get eighter all the balls to spawn or get them all to change the background when intersecting. I'm guessing it has something to do with the loop-function but I don't know how to fix it.

here my current code:

```
var balls = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    balls[i] = new ball(random(30, 370), random(30, 370), random(30));
  }
  player = new ball(100, 200, 25);

}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (balls[i].inter(player)) {
      background(200, 0, 0);
    } else {
      background(255, 255, 255);
    }
    balls[i].show();

  }

  player.show();
  player.x = mouseX;
  player.y = mouseY;
}

class ball {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }

  show() {
    noFill();
    circle(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
  }

  inter(other) {
    var d = dist(this.x, this.y, other.x, other.y);
    if (d < this.r + other.r) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

edit:
solved it!
The problem was that the background in the if-statement was on top off the other bubbles so they did not show up.

the new code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {

     if (balls[i].inter(player)) {
      background(200, 0, 0);

    } 


   }
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
  balls[i].show();
    }
```

Comment: when do you call your draw() function? (and the setup() function for completness)... so basically where is your draw loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you but I have both the draw and setup function